# urldecode() and rawurldecode() working locally but not on live server

Tags: php

I have the following line of code to retrieve and decode a URL before checking it against my database:

```
$urls = url_split(url_current());    

$url_page = (string)rawurldecode($url[0]);
```

The URL gets split and put into an array using the following functions:

```
function url_current () 
{
    // Check for HTTPS
    $http = 'http';

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") $http .= 's';

    $http .= '://';

    // Return URL
    return $http . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}

function url_split ($url)
{    
    // Retrieve URLs - Remove URL and split into array
    $url = explode('/', str_replace('http://www.siteurl.com', '', $url));

    // Build new array, remove blanks
    $urls = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($url); $i++)
    {
        if ($url[$i] != '') $urls[] = $url[$i];
    }

    // Return array
    return $urls;
}
```

This is working on my local server (using Zend) but it isn't working on my live server.  This shouldn't be an issue with the $_SEVER variables as these are all returning the correct data.  I've no idea why this would perform differently on my local server compared to my live server.  Is there any set up in the php ini that might be causing this?

On my local server **yrj%C3%B6laitinen** produces **yrjölaitinen** but on my live server it produces **yrjÃ¶laitinen**.

Comment: Did you try to debug this at all?

Comment: I've updated my post to show an example of what is being produced.

Comment: Define "on my live server it produces". The data being emitted appears to be the same; what differs is interpretation. So I suspect that your test server advertises Charset UTF8, and your live server advertises ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 (aka Latin1). Check out server headers with Firebug or other HTTP communication inspecting tools.

Comment: I have Firebug running but I can't see anything about the server headers. Can you direct me more specifically to where I can find this information?

Comment: @chapmanio: Open the "Net" panel, choose the HTML filter and hit reload. You should get just one request, click to expand and look at the Headers tab.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything about the charset:
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2012 10:32:50 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PleskLin

Comment: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=e2o5rvjvf2jp35lhijhsl52im1
Host: www.websiteurl.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved.  I'm afraid this was linked my PDO database connection.  I hadn't updated the code to force UTF-8:

```
// Connect to database
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

// Injection prevention
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Apologies for wasting anyones time looking at this.  It was my own stupid fault!

Comment: It won't let me for two days, curse you Stack Overflow! *shakes fist*